# Python equivalent for do.call(rbind, lapply()) from R

Tags: python, r, pandas, lapply

One of my main tools in my workflows is the `do.call(rbind, lapply())` as exampled here in R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10, 5), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))

getp <- function(var) {
  return(t.test(df1[, var], df2[, var])$p.value)
}

list <- c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')
ps <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, getp))
ps
                 [,1]
[1,] 6.232025e-09
[2,] 2.128019e-09
[3,] 5.824713e-08
```

This creates a nice column of p-values. In the real world I would pull out a one row data.frame with each column having useful model stats. With the goal being to iterate over many columns with the same model type and see the fit/effects.

In python, I can create a similar function:

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ttest_ind 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1' : np.random.randn(10), 'x2' : np.random.randn(10), 'x3' : np.random.randn(10)}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1' : np.random.randn(10)+5, 'x2' : np.random.randn(10)+5, 'x3' : np.random.randn(10)+5}) 
def getp(var):
    print(ttest_ind(df1[var], df2[var])[1])

vars = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
```

I can print all pvalues to the console via:

```
for i in vars:
    getp(i)

9.67944232638e-08
1.82163637251e-08
2.00410346438e-10
```

But I'd like to save this as an object as one column with three rows similar to in R. Is this possible?

Thanks!

The actual function may look something like this:

```
def getMoreThanP(var):
    out = pd.DataFrame({'mean1' : [np.mean(df1[var])], 'mean2' : [np.mean(df2[var])], 'pvalue' : [ttest_ind(df1[var], df2[var])[1]]})
    print(out)

for i in vars:
    getMoreThanP(i)

...     getMoreThanP(i)
     mean1     mean2        pvalue
0  0.24452  4.824327  2.438985e-11
      mean1     mean2        pvalue
0  0.187176  4.969862  1.115546e-11
      mean1     mean2        pvalue
0  0.035759  5.249378  1.525264e-08
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of passing variables one by one, you can pass all three:

```
ttest_ind(df1[vars], df2[vars])[1]
Out[85]: array([  4.97835813e-11,   8.30544748e-08,   9.24917262e-07])
```

The returning object is a one-dimensional array. If you want a dataframe instead

```
pd.DataFrame(ttest_ind(df1[vars], df2[vars])[1])
```

This is mainly because ttest_ind accepts array like objects. For getMoreThanP, you can use a combination of pd.concat and map:

```
def getMoreThanP(var):
    out = pd.DataFrame({'mean1' : [np.mean(df1[var])], 'mean2' : [np.mean(df2[var])], 'pvalue' : [ttest_ind(df1[var], df2[var])[1]]})
    return out

pd.concat(map(getMoreThanP, vars))
# pd.concat(map(getMoreThanP, vars), ignore_index=True) if you want to reset index
Out[134]: 
      mean1     mean2        pvalue
0 -0.021791  4.964985  4.978358e-11
0  0.087019  4.610332  8.305447e-08
0 -0.084168  4.680124  9.249173e-07
```

Note that I changed the definition of getMoreThanP to return the dataframe instead of printing it.

Comment: My mind is blown that ttest_ind takes in an array. Very cool. But I'm not sure it solves my full problem since what I'll really be doing is wanting to do a bunch of stuff with each variable that is passed. My post has now been updated to reflect a little closer to the sort of function I may write.

Comment: Do you want to print the values or return an array (a 3x3 matrix in the end)?

Comment: I want to return an 3x3 `matrix`/`DataFrame`. With the loop method I only know how to see the result via `print()` which is why I'm using it here. I assume I'd use `return` using the proper method.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!